# Flask/Jinja2: Macro calling macro with context

Tags: python, flask, macros, jinja2

I have a template that contains some macros:

```
{% macro input(id, editable=current_user.is_active) %}
  ... some content ...
{% endmacro %}

{% macro the_form() %}
  {{input('id1')}}
  {{input('id2', False)}}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then I want to use those macros in another template:

```
{% from 'forms.html' import the_form with context %}

{{ the_form() }}
```

But I always get an error, `name 'l_current_user' is not defined`.

Why is that `l_current_user` and not `current_user`?

And how can I give nested macros access to the `current_user` variable?